# Why FileNotFoundException when I Assembly.Load an assembly that is surely present?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, azure

In my Windows Azure role C# code I do the following:

```
Assembly.Load( "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" );
```

and `FileNotFoundException` is thrown. The problem is an assembly with such name is present and has even loaded before the code above is run - I see a corresponding line in the debugger "Output" window and when I do:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(
    assembly => assembly.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime"));
```

the result is `true` and if I use `Where()`, then `SingleOrDefault()` I get a reference to a corresponding `Assembly` object.

Why can't I load an assembly with `Assembly.Load()`?

Comment: Maybe it is not this assembly, but one of its dependencies, such as a native dll, that is missing?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Maybe, but the very same assembly has already been loaded - I see that in debugger output.

Comment: I turn to use absolute path: `Assembly.LoadFrom(path)`, I'm on web server and I use the path as `string path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "bin\\XXXX.dll"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That Load() call can only succeed if Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll is stored in your app's probing path.  By default the same directory as your EXE.  Problem is, it isn't stored there, it is stored in the GAC.

The point of the GAC is to act as a depository of assemblies with the same name but different [AssemblyVersion]s, culture or processor architecture.  Which is the problem with your Load(), you don't specify any.  There is no reasonable way that fusion can pick an assembly for you, it is apt to give you the wrong one.  So it doesn't bother, even if there is only one to pick from.

Specifying the full AsssemblyName.FullName is required.  Use Project + Add Reference to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

You should load it with a full assembly qualified name.

Comment: I don't want to mess with the version info - I don't care of it. How do I load the assembly then?

Comment: Sadly, if it's a signed assembly, you must load it with this full assembly qualified name. No way. Imagine if you install it in the GAC and you've 2 o 3 versions of same assembly? What would be the one that you get when you load without a qualified name? I know you'd prefer to avoid version info, but...? :D

Comment: Unless you use Assembly.LoadFrom - but then you have to provide the file path.

Comment: Yeah, @ozczecho, you're right. But I believe his case has no other approach, he's loading a Microsoft assembly that would be installed in different locations depending on user's machine, so I wouldn't suggest to use LoadFrom in this case.

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN documentation:

```
// You must supply a valid fully qualified assembly name.            
        Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load
            ("SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3");
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx) says that you're meant to supply the *full* name for the assembly (including e.g. version information).

Using just a plain name for the assembly will fail if the assembly is normally loaded from e.g. the GAC. E.g.:

```
        try
        {
            Assembly.Load("System");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(
        assembly => assembly.FullName.StartsWith("System")));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Exhibits similar behaviour.